# setItemChecked not working on ListFragment after screen rotation

Tags: android, listview, rotation, fragment, highlighting

I've got problem with highlighting an item on a ListView inside a Fragment after screen rotation. As my code is inspired from FragmentLayout example in ApiDemos, I've made test on it and the same problem occurs as described:

Start the application in portrait mode, select an item then rotate the device in landscape mode. The previously selected item is correctly highlighted with details fragment displaying the correct text. Switch back in portrait mode then select another item. Now when switching in landscape mode the "first" selected item is still highlighted and the details fragment displays the correct text, the one of the "second" selected item.

Why a wrong item is highlighted? There is an explicit call to getListView.setItemChecked(second_item_index, true) in the list fragment but it keeps the "first" item highlighted. I've tried to add setNotifyOnChange and/or set all items to false before calling setItemChecked but that changes nothing.

Is this a bug or something is missing?

However, there is a workaround, I've simply implemented the onStart method to set the item:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mDualPane) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mCurCheckPosition, true);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if onStart should be used to work on the UI but it works.

Another idea?

Comment: same problem here. Step 1.- in portrait, select item 1. Step 2.- rotate to landscape, select items 2 and 3. Step 3.- back to portrait, only item 1 is selected